# Unable to bind to gridview in another usercontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have 3 user controls

One is the parent that holds a GridViewUserControl and a ExportUserControl

The GridViewUserControl and ExportUserControl have their own viewmodels.

When I click the ExportButton in the ExportUserControl I need to pass the gridview to a command in the ExportUserControl.  Everything I try is always passing null.

How would I do something like this? ( This is giving the error "binding.elementname cannot be set while using binding.relativesource"

```
        <telerik:RadButton Content="Export"
                           Command="{Binding ExportCommand}"
                           CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=view:GridViewUserControl}, ElementName=GridViewData}"
                           Margin="0,10,0,0" />
```

EDIT:  Parent Control looks like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.Sample1.View.ParentUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:GroundStation.Configuration.Viewer.View"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <view:ExportUserControl Margin="5" 
                         Grid.Column="0"
                         Grid.Row="2"
                         Grid.RowSpan="2"
                         MinWidth="150"
                         />
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" 
                      Width="5"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.RowSpan="3"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <view:GridViewUserControl 
            Margin="5" 
            Grid.Column="2"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: How does your parent user control look like? XAML/.cs

Comment: Updated Question with parent

Comment: Does your ParentUserControl know about the ViewModels of the two children user controls?
What's in Locator?

I see you're setting the DataContext of the parent. If the parent contains the ViewModels (for example ExportUserControlViewModel and GridViewUserControlViewModel properties) then you can do

`CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.GridViewUserControlViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=view:GridViewUserControl}}"`

I know this is not the view, but I don't think you can pass the view like this.

Comment: No they do not, I added to context to try with the mainviewmodel.  Right now it is just a control I am using to hold the two other conrols (if that makes sense.)  Locator is the MVVMLIGHT viewmodel locator

Comment: ok, I was thinking something like that with the mainviewmodel.  I will try it and let you know.